# How can i Load my main ViewController's view, from another viewcontroller's icon action?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, events, viewcontroller

I have a root ViewController class, and call the OnlineViewController's View like this:

```
- (void)eventTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

self.evc = [[EventViewController alloc]init];    
[self presentViewController:self.evc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

And I tried to Call The ViewController'S View from OnlineViewController, but it's failed :

```
-(void ) iconAction{
self.vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];

[self presentViewController:self.vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}
How Can I call ViewController's view?

Comment: means wants to go back `-(void)iconAction {  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil] }`

Comment: Did you Try self.vc.view;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try and dismiss this viewController rather than Presenting a new one

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

also make sure your `iconAction:` method is called.